# Proving an inequality on matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I feel that the following inequality should hold

$$
\|A \otimes xx^T\|_2 \le \|A\|_2,
$$

where $A$ is real, symmetric and positive semidefinite, $\otimes$ is the elementwise multiplication, $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the $\ell_2$ operator norm, and $-1 \le x \le 1$.

---

My attempt:

It feels like we should be able to prove it using triangle inequality. We need to prove that

$$\|A\|_2 - \|A \otimes xx^T\|_2  \ge 0.$$

However, triangle inequality can only provide an upper bound of the LHS, instead of a lower bound.

---

My attempt #2:
$$
\|A \otimes xx^T\|_2 = \|\text{diag}(x)\ A\ \text{diag}(x)\|_2 \le \|\text{diag}(x)\ A\ \text{diag}(x)\|_F \le \|\text{diag}(x)\|_2\|A\|_2\| \text{diag}(x)\|_F = x_{max} \sqrt{\sum_i^d x_i^2} \|A\|_2 \le \sqrt{d}\|A\|_2.
$$

Still not tight enough...

Comment: How are you justifying the last inequality?

Comment: @angryavian oops you are right. I made a mistake there. Back to square one! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there.  We have
$$
\|A \otimes xx^T\|_2 = \|\operatorname{diag}(x)A\operatorname{diag}(x)\|_2 \leq 
\|\operatorname{diag}(x)\|_2\cdot \|A\|_2 \cdot \|\operatorname{diag}(x)\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2.
$$

---

Regarding the inequality: we have $\|AB\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2 \|B\|_2$ in general.  That is, the $\ell^2$ operator norm (like any operator norm) is "submultiplicative".

One proof is as follows. We have $\|Ax\| \leq \|A\|_2 \|x\|_2$. Thus, 
$$
\|AB\|_2 = \max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \|A(Bx)\| \leq \max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \|A\|_2\cdot \|Bx\|_2
= \|A\|_2 \max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \cdot \|Bx\|_2 = \|A\|_2 \cdot \|B\|_2.
$$
I have used $\|\cdot\|_2$ to refer either to the $\ell_2$-norm or the associated operator norm (depending on whether the argument is a column-vector or a matrix).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain why the first inequality holds?

Comment: See my latest edit.  We have $\|ABC\| \leq \|AB\| \cdot \|C\| \leq \|A\| \cdot \|B\| \cdot \|C\|$.

Comment: For more information on matrix norms, I suggest checking Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* (chapter 5 if I remember correctly).

Comment: I see it now. Thx!